# Extract strings from file and save in another using c#

Tags: c#, string, file

I have .txt file with 300 000 rows. Is there any way to extract specific strings(lines) from that file and save in another .txt or excel only extracted lines ?
I talk about log file where i save some requests with time taken for every request. What I want to do is to extract only the time of each request then I'll calculate average time taken.

Hope you guys understand what i talking about.

Edit:
Format of .txt file is plain text and every request end with. So i have:

```
Starting date
//body of response from server
End date
Time: 3150,0792 ms <--- time taken
```

So, I have 10 000 requests and 10 000 responses. I need to extract only Time of each because will take me a lot of time manually to scroll whole .txt file and check every Time.

Comment: How about a few lines of your txt file so we can see the format, then an example of what you want the extracted text file to look like.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Use [`StreamReader.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) in a loop and you're good to go.

Comment: @CodeCaster, That's not a good idea if he has 300 000 rows. He'd be better of reading a couple of lines a time.

Comment: Of course, what have you tried? Regular Expression are probably a good starting point http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx

Comment: @CodeCaster That's not really the whole story. I don't think it's ever necessary to use `File.ReadAllLines` given the presence of `File.ReadLines`. Besides, isn't this really a question about reading and writing CSV type files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    private void extract_lines(string filein, string fileout)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filein))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileout))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains("what you looking for"))
                    {
                        writer.Write(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually this extract everything what i need.

Answer (score 4):

you can achieve it by File Class

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText("File2.txt")) 
{
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(@"d:\File1.txt"))
    {
        if (line.Contains("TheWordInLine"))//This is the line you want by matching something
        {
                sw.WriteLine("line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create the `StreamWriter` only once in a scope external to the loop?

Comment: Ok, but why i get in file `Time: ` ? Should be `Time: Something ms` ?

Answer (score 4):

You can try using [`MemoryMappedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx) and [`TextReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.aspx) combined. MMF allows you to access large files and text reader allows you to process file in a line by line manner.

```
using (var mmf = 
            MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(@"c:\large.data", FileMode.Open
{
    using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
    {
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(stream);
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you could use [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)/[StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx):

```
using (var input = File.OpenText("input.log"))
using (var output = File.CreateText("output.log"))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = input.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (SomeConditionOnLine(line))
        {
            output.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

This will read the input file line by line, thus having only a single line in memory at once and if this line satisfies some condition that you are looking for write it to the output file. It will be fast and consume very little memory and it will work for huge input files.

Comment: This work also, but write only `Time`. Should be `Time: time ms`. How to take also time

Answer (score 2):

As others already said, it would be useful to have an example of the format.
Anyway maybe you can find this tool useful:

http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/

I use it at work and it allows you to parse and write to different file formats.
Hope it helps